# Can I run a back-end script at place of cron job?

Tags: php, cron

I have an hourly cron job in my project that checks for any new orders placed in the system. If there are any, it executes some required processing; otherwise it just completes.

Is there some way I can change this, so that any new order immediately triggers a back-end script?

Comment: Yes, probably. Anything else you're wondering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [php](/questions/tagged/php) you can easely [run bash/shell commands](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php) instead of having a `cron` that run every hour. Just execute the script when the order is validated.